# Extend road grid into two way road

Tags: netlogo

I am working on traffic simulation using netlogo. In attached image, i want to extend the road grids into two way road grid i.e. increase the width of each road grid. Here is the code that will need update but I am unable to do it myself.

```
set roads patches with [
    (floor ((pxcor + max-pxcor - floor (grid-x-inc - 1)) mod grid-x-inc) = 0) or
    (floor ((pycor + max-pycor) mod grid-y-inc) = 0)
  ]
```

[image: road grid]

Answer (score 1):

Here is code that makes wider roads.

I tried to separate out the left lanes from the right lane so you can see what is happening if that helps you figure out where the cars should go.

I also separated the x-offset and y-offset values so you can adjust the grid in case you want to.

**This code assumes that max-pxcor = 32, max-pycor = 32, and patch size = 6, so that the whole thing fits the same physical view area.**

```
globals [
  left-lanes
  right-lanes
  roads
]

to setup
  clear-all

  ;; set the number of patches between lanes
  let grid-x-inc 13
  let grid-y-inc 13

  ;; offsets move the lanes slightly more to the right or further up
  let x-offset grid-x-inc - 3  
  let y-offset   -2

  ;; color the background
  ask patches    [set pcolor lime]

  ;; create the lanes
  set left-lanes patches with [
    (floor ((pxcor + max-pxcor - x-offset) mod grid-x-inc) = 2) or   
    (floor ((pycor + max-pycor - y-offset) mod grid-y-inc) = 2)
  ] 

  set right-lanes patches with [
    (floor ((pxcor + max-pxcor - x-offset) mod grid-x-inc) =  1) or   
    (floor ((pycor + max-pycor - y-offset) mod grid-y-inc) =  3)
  ] 


  ;; color the lanes for debugging purposes
  ; ask left-lanes [set pcolor yellow]
  ; ask right-lanes [set pcolor (yellow - 1)  ]

  ;; merge left and right lanes into roads
  set roads patches with [ member? self left-lanes or member? self right-lanes]
  ask roads [ set pcolor yellow]

  reset-ticks
end

to go   
  tick
end
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow you have to ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 1):

OK,  now I see what you are trying to do.  You have a bigger problem than just **drawing** wider roads.

And I see now that you probably just want traffic just to go in one direction on each wider road, instead of simulating traffic going both directions.

OK, so you need to solve several design problems before anyone can answer your question about code.

(1) What do you want to **display**?   Do you want just a wider yellow road?  Or do you want pretty roads with lines along the sides like in the "Traffic 2 Lanes" model?

(2) Do you want the cars to **actually use the two lanes**, and include behavior such as changing-lanes and passing, like the "Traffic 2 Lanes" model?

AND ... the "Traffic 2 Lanes" model already includes all the logic and code you need for drawing wider roads, which would solve one of the two related questions you originally posted.   Even if you only want fat yellow roads, not fancy roads with lines on them, the same logic could be used and you can just remove the part that draws lines.

This answers your first question:

> i want to ... increase the width of each road grid.

BUT ... You actually asked a much harder question in your comment and in your original post's title:

> i want to extend the road grids into **two way** road grid

I am not sure whether your original meaning has survived translation into English.

To me, a "two way road" means one road with two lanes,  where there is traffic going both directions on the same road.  Some cars would be heading North and some cars would be heading South.

This is **far more complicated** than the "Traffic Grid" problem in the Model Library  In the "Traffic Grid" problem each road is only one lane wide, but it is also "one way".

Finally,  I see that you did not give credit to Uri Wilensky or mention the models in the Model Library that is the source of most of the code you posted.  It will be obvious to your college teacher that you copied large sections of code from someone else's work -- you should give credit to that person and cite the source of that code. It is still a major effort for your college final project to merge the logic from two models into one more complex model and get it to function.